# Paypal API integration error: using "details.seller_receivable_breakdown.gross_amount" says it is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I've integrated a Paypal button into an app. When I try to get the gross amount of the order that was just placed, it says it is undefined in the browser.

Here's the code i'm using:

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {

return actions.order.get().then(function(details) {

alert(details.seller_receivable_breakdown.gross_amount.value)

...
```

I'm in sandbox mode, btw.. Is this something that only works in production mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No order has been placed after a `.get()`, you need `.capture()` for an order to be placed.  See the sample at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Use `console.log(details)` to see all the information

The information you want may not be there in the order capture response.  You can use the V2 payments API to get more information about a capture: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_get

Comment: I actually tried this: 
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {

            return actions.order.get().then(function (orderDetails) {
              
              var paypalGrossAmountReceived = orderDetails.seller_receivable_breakdown.gross_amount.value;
              var paypalGrossAmountReceived2 = orderDetails.purchase_units.amount.value;
              console.log('gross amount: ' + paypalGrossAmountReceived);
              console.log('gross amount 2: ' + paypalGrossAmountReceived2);

Comment: I also tried reversing it so the .capture() is nested within the .get(). Still says it's undefined. Is it cause i'm using sandbox mode?

Comment: This shows the .capture() nested inside the .get() https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/confirmation-page/

Comment: Ok so I don't need the .get() at all. When I use:

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!!

Don't need to use the .get() function at all, .capture() works fine. I had tried using this in one of my many attempts before posting here:
details.purchase_units[0].amount.value;

The problem was that purchase_units returns as a json array, so I needed to add [0].

Here's what worked:
details.purchase_units[0].amount.value;

:)